# How to write GroupJoin Lambda Expression in Linq query?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

Here I have a lambda expression which selects the best joke by the highest rating.

So the relationship looks like this: 1 joke has many ratings.

The lambda query for selecting the best joke is as follows.

```
Joke best = jokes.GroupJoin(context.Ratings,  // DBContext
                            j => j.ID,
                            r => r.JokeID,
                            (j, r) => new {
                                           bestJoke = j,
                                           sum = r.Sum(s => s.Rating1)
                                          })
                 .OrderByDescending(j => j.sum)
                 .First().bestJoke;
```

I struggling to write this into linq query.

I tried so far.

```
    Joke best2 = from j in jokes
                 join r in context.Ratings on j.ID equals r.JokeID
                 group j by j into g
                 select new {
                      bestJoke = j,
                      } ...
```

Could anyone please help me out? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GroupJoin` can be expressed using `join .. in .. on .. into` syntax:

> **7.16.2.4 `From`, `let`, `where`, `join` and `orderby` clauses**
>
> A query expression with a join clause with an into followed by a
>   select clause
>
> ```
> from x1 in e1
> join x2 in e2 on k1 equals k2 into g
> select v
> ```
>
> is translated into
>
> ```
> ( e1 ) . GroupJoin( e2 , x1 => k1 , x2 => k2 , ( x1 , g ) => v )
> ```
>
> A query expression with a join clause with an into followed by
>   something other than a select clause
>
> ```
> from x1 in e1
> join x2 in e2 on k1 equals k2 into g
> …
> ```
>
> is translated into
>
> ```
> from * in ( e1 ) . GroupJoin(
>   e2 , x1 => k1 , x2 => k2 , ( x1 , g ) => new { x1 , g })
> …
> ```

But as you can see you can't make it generate `(j, r) => new { bestJoke = j, sum = r.Sum(s => s.Rating1) }` into `GroupJoin` call, so you'd have to select the sum later in separate expression.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var best2 = (from joke in jokes
             join rating in context.Ratings 
             on joke.ID equals rating.JokeID
             group item by joke into gr
             orderby gr.Sum(x=>x.Rating) descending
             ).FirstOrDefault();

if(best2!=null)
    bestJoke = best2.Key;
```

However, you should keep in mind that the above query during the compilation time would be converted to an equivalent query written in fluent syntax (like the first one). The query syntax is a syntactic sugar that is offered to us.